# Which application is triggering a "To use the 'java' command-line tool you need to install a JDK" dialog?

Tags: macos, java

My CPU usage suddenly rose up to 80-100%. Couldn't find the trigger, so I just totally deleted Java from my Mac. Now I keep getting this popup:

> To use the "java" command-line tool you need to install a JDK.
>
> Click "More info..." to visit the Java Developer Kit download website.

How can I know which program is trying to run Java? Keep getting this every few seconds now.

[image: popup]

Answer (score 7):

For my sister this was caused by Facebook videochat, with a slightly different message:

> To view this web content, you need to install the Java Runtime Environment.
>
> Click "More info..." to visit the website for the Java Runtime Environment.

We debugged quite randomly, and could not find a way to tell what triggered this dialog. But [the following Apple Support Communities post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602999) explained how to find it by trial and error:

> Here are the steps I used to correct, as even after removal from Launch control it kept returning on reboot:
>
> 1. Open a Terminal Prompt
> 2. Show non Apple startup Agents. At $ execute
>
>    ```
>    launchctl list | grep -v apple
>    ```
>
>    This will look something like the following.
>
>    ```
>    PID Status Label
>    -   0      org.openbsd.ssh-agent
>    282 0      com.symantec.symsecondarylaunch.application
>    274 0      com.symantec.quickmenu.application
>    -   0      com.google.keystone.system.agent
>    -   0      com.valvesoftware.steamclean
>    -   0      com.oracle.java.Java-Updater
>    276 0      com.Logitech.Control Center.Daemon
>    302 0      com.google.Chrome.62228
>    -   1      com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.updater
>    295 0      com.symantec.scannotification.application
>    -   0      net.tunnelblick.tunnelblick.LaunchAtLogin
>    275 0      com.symantec.savdiskmountnotify.application
>    317 0      net.tunnelblick.tunnelblick.119880
>    ```
>
>    One of the returned items is likely your issue, mine was also `com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.updater`
> 3. Change to the Agents directory, `cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents/`
> 4. I also had to remove the actual agent files, as it kept re-appearing on reboot. You can view those on your system and remove. List out the items in directory: `ls`
>
>    ```
>    SharedServices.Agent.plist
>    com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.plist
>    com.valvesoftware.steamclean.plist
>    net.tunnelblick.tunnelblick.LaunchAtLogin.plist
>    org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist
>    ```
> 5. From `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` execute
>
>    ```
>    rm com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.plist
>    ```
> 6. Also remove from Launch control with
>
>    ```
>    launchctl remove com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.updater
>    ```
> 7. Exit and reboot

If I recall correctly then this videochat thing might also have been a plugin in her browser, which we then already removed earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (setting JAVA_HOME to "Library\Internet Plug-In\JavaAppletPlugin.plugin\Contents\Home\bin"), after install Java from http://www.java.com/:

***export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/***

***export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH***

To make the new path stick permanently you need to create a .bash_profile file in your home directory and set the path there. This file control various Terminal environment preferences including the path:

***cd***

Move into home directory:

***nano .bash_profile***

Create the .bash_profile file with a command line editor called nano:

***export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH***

Save the file in nano by clicking ‘control’ +’o’ and confirming the name of the file is .bash_profile by hitting return. And the ‘control’+’x’ to exit nano:

So now when the Terminal is relaunched or a new window made and you check the the path by:

***echo $PATH***

You will get the new path at the front followed by the default path locations, all the time

**/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin//bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin :/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin**

If you have problems with:

***export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/***

Change to this:

***export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home***

Comment: How does this answer *"How can I know which program is trying to run Java?"*